# ¿Cómo rellenar valores 'na' en un DataFrame, con el valor de un fila posterior?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, jupyterhub

Dispongo de un primer DataFraame con una sola columna 'Datos' y un índice con fechas que en el rango 2021-2023.
Creo un segundo DataFrame con fechas en el rango 2013-2023.
Necesito obtener un DataFrame con un rango de fechas entre 2013 y 2023 en el que, los valores 'na' en la columna 'Datos', desde  2013 hasta 2021, sean el primer valor de la columna 'Datos' del segundo DataFrame, y el resto hasta 2023, los valores dde la columna 'Datos' del segundo DataFrame.

He probado con el siguiente código, pero en esos primeros egistros, aparece 'na'.

```
import pandas as pd
import datetime as dt
from datetime import datetime

# Ruta el fichero .csv
path = '/media/enri/Mi_Proyecto/Py_Proyecto_2022/Gestion-Conservadora-de-Activos_Financieros/Mi_cartera/Datos/'
os.chdir(path + './R4_PP/')

file = 'EpsvGlobalAccionesPP.csv'
# Importación de datos a un DataFrame
data = pd.read_csv(file ,index_col = "Date", 
              decimal  =",", parse_dates = True, usecols = ["Date", "Close"],
              na_values = ["nan"], sep='\t') 

#start_date = '2013-1-4'
#end_date = '2023-2-30'
start_date = datetime(2013, 1, 4)
end_date = datetime(2023, 1, 30)
# DataFrame con todas las fechas del período
df_all_dates = pd.DataFrame(index = pd.date_range(start = start_date, end = end_date))

df = df_all_dates.join(data[['Close']], how = 'left').fillna(method = 'ffill')
```

Me devuelve

[image: DataFrame devuelto]

¿Cómo puedo resolver este problema?. Agradeceré ayuda.

Comment: bfill en vez de ffill

Comment: Gracias. También cambiando esta sentencia. 
df = df_all_dates.join(data[['Close']], how = 'left').fillna(data.iloc[0]) 

parasustituir las celdas con 'na' por el dato en la primera fila del DataFrame 'data'.

Answer (score 0):

Podríamos utilizar el método **concat()**

```
import pandas as pd

# Crear DataFrame 1
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'Date': ['2022-01-01', '2022-01-02', '2022-01-03'], 'Acatis': [10, 11, 12]})
df1.set_index('Date', inplace=True)

# Crear DataFrame 2
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'Date': ['2023-01-03', '2023-01-04', '2023-01-05'], 'True': [13, 14, 15]})
df2.set_index('Date', inplace=True)

# Concatenar DataFrames
concat_df = pd.concat([df1, df2], axis = 1)

# Mostrar DataFrame resultante
concat_df.bfill().ffill()

rellenando los valores faltantes con NaN utilizando **bfill()** y **ffill()**
```

En el caso de que las columnas tengan nombres diferentes, se puede utilizar el parámetro **join** de la **función concat()** para especificar cómo se unen los DataFrames. El valor predeterminado del parámetro join es **outer**, que crea un nuevo DataFrame con todas las filas y columnas de ambos DataFrames, y rellena los valores faltantes con NaN.

En tu ejemplo, el DataFrame df1 tiene una columna llamada 'Acatis' y el DataFrame df2 tiene una columna llamada 'True'. Al concatenar los dos DataFrames con pd.concat([df1, df2], axis=1), la columna 'Acatis' del DataFrame df1 se ubicará en la primera columna del DataFrame resultante y la columna 'True' del DataFrame df2 se ubicará en la segunda columna. Si no se especifica el parámetro join, se utilizará la opción predeterminada 'outer' y el DataFrame resultante tendrá filas con valores NaN para las fechas en las que no hay cotizaciones.

En tu código, parece que se utiliza el método bfill() (backward fill) y ffill() (forward fill) para rellenar los valores faltantes en el DataFrame resultante. Estos métodos son útiles para rellenar valores faltantes en un DataFrame, pero no son necesarios en este caso ya que el DataFrame resultante no tendrá valores faltantes si los DataFrames de origen tienen todas las fechas únicas.

En resumen, si las columnas tienen nombres diferentes, se puede utilizar el parámetro join de la función concat() para especificar cómo se unen los DataFrames. Si los DataFrames de origen tienen todas las fechas únicas, no se necesitará rellenar los valores faltantes en el DataFrame resultante.

No necesariamente es necesario utilizar los métodos ffill() y bfill() después de usar join() con el parámetro how='outer'. La función join() rellena automáticamente los valores faltantes con NaN y al especificar how='outer', se asegura de que se incluyan todas las fechas del rango total de ambos DataFrames en el DataFrame resultante.

Sin embargo, en algunos casos puede ser útil utilizar ffill() y bfill() para rellenar los valores faltantes con el último valor anterior disponible y el siguiente valor disponible, respectivamente. Por ejemplo, si hay días en los que no hay cotizaciones y se desea rellenar los valores faltantes con los valores de cotización del último día disponible, se puede utilizar ffill() para rellenar los valores faltantes con el último valor anterior disponible.

En resumen, si los DataFrames de origen tienen todas las fechas únicas, la función join() rellenará automáticamente los valores faltantes con NaN. Si se desea rellenar los valores faltantes con los métodos ffill() y bfill(), esto se puede hacer después de unir los DataFrames con join(), pero no es necesario si el DataFrame resultante no tiene valores faltantes.

```
import pandas as pd

# Crear DataFrame 1
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'Date': ['2022-01-01', '2022-01-02', '2022-01-03'], 'Acatis': [10, 11, 12]})
df1.set_index('Date', inplace=True)

# Crear DataFrame 2
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'Date': ['2023-01-03', '2023-01-04', '2023-01-05'], 'True': [13, 14, 15]})
df2.set_index('Date', inplace=True)

# Unir DataFrames
joined_df = df1.join(df2, how='outer')

# Rellenar valores NaN con forward-fill y back-fill
joined_df = joined_df.ffill().bfill()

# Mostrar DataFrame resultante
```

joined_df